# PHP How To Return Latest Entries Per Set Of Users?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I am trying to return back the latest message based on timestamp from a group of Senders.

The basic table and qry looks like this

```
SELECT senderName, messages
FROM MessageTable
WHERE receiverID = 1

(output)
Joe "Hey"
Bob "Yo"
Jim "Blah"
Joe "What's up"
```

I want to get the latest message from EACH sender. I thought to use ORDER BY and LIMIT but it just returns 1 message from the entire qry. Which is not the result I’m looking for.

```
SELECT senderName, messages
FROM MessageTable
WHERE receiverID = 1
ORDER BY sentDate ASC LIMIT 1

(output)
Bob "Yo"
```

I would like to have this kind of output, where only Joe's latest message is returned along with the other Sender's latest message.

```
Bob "Yo"
Jim "Blah"
Joe "What's up"
```

I've looked at another question on stackoverflow, but it didn't make sense to me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384142/how-to-get-latest-record-for-each-day-when-there-are-multiple-entries-per-day

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is your friend http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

You could do some thing like this:

```
SELECT senderName, messages
FROM MessageTable
GROUP BY senderName
ORDER BY sentDate DESC
```

Comment: I always treated that usage of `GROUP BY` as unreliable, is I couldn't find any documentation for it's use (using fields that are NOT listed in the `GROUP BY` clause, and NOT wrapped in an aggregate function). I figured it was a MySQL quirk that couldn't be counted on (most other RDBMS's would reject this statement, I believe).

Comment: @liamgriffiths This is getting there! It now returns each Sender's message but not Joe's latest. It is returning Joe's earliest. I tried ASC and that just changed the order in which the entire return was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some searching and trial and error, this query returned what i was looking for:

```
SELECT a.senderName, a.messages, a.sentDate
FROM MessageTable AS a,
(
    SELECT senderName, MAX(sentDate) as max_date
    FROM MessageTable
    WHERE ReceiverID = 1
    GROUP BY senderName
) AS b
WHERE a.senderName = b.senderName
AND a.sentDate = b.max_date;
```

All the credit goes to this site: http://forums.devarticles.com/general-sql-development-47/select-max-datetime-problem-10210.html

Answer (score 0):

The type of the queries is called "Ranking queries" and they do usually require some level of competence. Here is a similar question: [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrievin-the-last-record-in-each-group)

It is better if you would operate with numeric ids instead of strings to make the query efficient enough.